# why future_promise error is "Unhandled" with onRejected

Tags: r, exception, future, r-promises

Using `future_promise` with `catch(.)` (or `then(onRejected=)`), the error is still marked as "Unhandled" even though I think I'm attempting to handle it.

```r
library(future)
library(promises)
plan(multicore, workers = 3)

Sys.getpid()
# [1] 1270066
nbrOfFreeWorkers()
# [1] 3
thisproc <- promises::future_promise({
  setTimeLimit(elapsed = 2, transient = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(3)
  1L
}, seed = TRUE) %>%
  promises::then(
    function(val) {
      message("survived: ", val)
      val
    }) %>%
  catch(
    function(error) {
      message("terminated: ", substring(conditionMessage(error), 1, 16))
      NULL
    })
# terminated: Unexpected resul
# Unhandled promise error: Unexpected result (of class ‘NULL’ != ‘FutureResult’) retrieved for MulticoreFuture future (label = ‘<none>’, expression = ‘{; setTimeLimit(elapsed = 2, transient \
# = TRUE); Sys.sleep(3); 1L; }’):
```

once that returned, then

```r
nbrOfFreeWorkers()
# [1] 2
resetWorkers(plan())
# NULL
nbrOfFreeWorkers()
# [1] 3
```

(I used `substring` just to differentiate an error-like string messaged by my function, and the full condition message being `cat`ted to the console.)

1. It reports "Unhandled" despite the code handling it (the `terminated:` is printed);
2. It reports it *twice*;

and **most importantly**,

3. The worker is not freed until I explicitly free it, despite the `then`-chain functioning.

According to [the source](https://github.com/rstudio/promises/blob/a821b8845f72862f12df9b4926ab7de71880ced7/R/promise.R#L75-L93), it appears that `rejectionHandled` is only referenced/set in this one file, and it *should* be setting the flag:

```r
    doRejectFinalReason = function(reason) {
      private$value <- reason
      private$state <- "rejected"

      later::later(function() {
          lapply(private$onRejected, function(f) {
            private$rejectionHandled <- TRUE
            f(private$value)
          })
          private$onRejected <- list()

        later::later(~{
          if (!private$rejectionHandled) {
            # warning() was unreliable here
            cat(file=stderr(), "Unhandled promise error: ", reason$message, "\n", sep = "")
          }
        })
      })
    }
```

I assumed that since `f(private$value)` *is called* (as evidenced by the `"terminated:"` message I inserted), then the `private_rejectionHandled` should already have been updated. There are no other errors in this pipe, so it should not have reset the `rejectionHandled` flag.

Incidentally, I tried (without success) to call `later::run_now()` throughout the process to make sure that all promises are being run, though I was only stabbing in the dark (and it did not change the result).

Also, I can find `attributes(thisproc)$promise_impl$.__enclos_env__$private$rejectionHandled`, see it is `FALSE`, and change it to `TRUE`, but we still see the "Unhandled" console output, indicating something else is at work here. https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/86#issuecomment-1252420305 is related (or perhaps the same thing).

---

Linux, R-4.2.2, future-1.30.0 (1.31.0 is released), promises-1.2.0.1, later-1.3.0.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `promises` but I noticed two things in case it helps: 1) running the example in `reprex()` doesn't show any message while running it manually shows the same message you have, 2) in both cases (`reprex` and manual), there are 3 free workers after the operation whereas you only have 2. R 4.2.2, Windows 10, future 1.31.0, promises 1.2.0.1, later 1.3.0

Comment: `future` in `plan(multicore)` behaves differently in windows than in linux, unfortunately (no fork in windows). The issue is with a deployed environment, so while I am curious that the symptoms may be different, it is unfortunately a different mechanic. Thanks @bretauv

Comment: Status: bullets 1 and 2 appear to be resolved in issue [promises#86](https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/86); bullet 3 still unresolved but recently filed as [future#665](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/665), which provides a little more detail than in this SO question.